# How to use jquery lazy with src?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I want to use [jQuery.Lazy();](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) in article content, but this need **data-src** attribute in `<img>`

I have 170.000 article in database and all used src, please give me a solution for use [jQuery.Lazy();](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) without **img data-src**, use only **img src** !

can i add data-src with jquery in all images ?

Comment: Post relevant code used to append these images to the DOM because you have to change the attribute **before** appending it as HTML markup. But better would be to change it directly in database instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery.Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) is my Plugin. So a few words to your problem:

In general, you can change the attribute used by the plugin to lazy load images. The config parameter is simply named `attribute`. The default name is `data-src`, but you can change them on initialization, for example:

```
$('img').Lazy({
    attribute: 'data-image'
});
```

But to your question about using `src`: it's **impossible**!

Every browser will look for `<img />` tags and its `src` attribute. If it finds them, they will instantly load the images. There is no way to break this and load them on a later time. That's why all lazy-load plugins uses a different attribute on the image tags. You just can't prevent the browser from loading the images instantly.

You have to find a way to change your image tags. As you seems to write the whole html to your database, it's pretty hard to change later on. That's why you should not write plain html to database and use things like markup instead.

A simple idea would be, to replace the html image tag, right before you deliver it to the browser. You need to check if this is fast enough for you. But at least it's an idea.

Good luck.